# Use dropdown widget, select value from one column, return value from another column in dataframe

Tags: python, ipywidgets

A little mockup below. In this case, I am selecting from df['num_wings'] and passing that selection into a new variable.

However, what I really want to pass into identvar is the value from df['num_legs']. So, select an option from one column but retrieve the value from the same row in another column. In my case, I need to be able to select an email address from the list so I can retrieve a long unique identifier string. Not sure how to get there? How do I retrieve the value of num_legs by selecting the value from num_wings?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
df

widg = Dropdown(options = df['num_wings'])
display(widg)

identvar = widg.value
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I retrieve the value from the other column? Here, how would I select from num_wings but return num_legs.

Comment: Can you show an example of what the desired result should be? Why can't you just use `df['num_legs']`?

Comment: In my use case, I need to retrieve a long string variable that is essentially nonsense. I can pass that into the selection list no problem, but then have no idea who it is I am picking. So if I pick from an email, I know who it is I am selecting and want to use that to get to the associated nonsense string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter a dataframe based on one column and retrieve the values of another column, then `df.loc[df['num_wings'] == widg.value, 'num_legs']` should do what you want to do. *But* if you have multiple things with the same number of wings, then you will retrieve that many rows' values for legs.

You might be better off setting `num_wings` as your index to the dataframe, then the call will simplify to `df.loc[widg.value, 'num_legs]`, but this still doesn't get round any duplications.

Comment: That got me most of the way there, thank you! Was trying to make it more complicated than it needed to be! The result in my case will always be unique, so passing ```idvar = df.loc[df['num_wings'] == widg.value, 'num_legs'].values[0]``` gets me the variable I need. Thank you again!